# collections are not shown in database in Robomongo 0.8.5

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

In my mongodb one database contains thee collections, but when i run Robomongo 0.8.5 collections of my database are not shown(left side of the Robomongo 0.8.5(file explorer).

If i run following query in Robomongo 0.8.5, it shows all the collection.

```
db.stats()
```

another query to show collection

```
db.collectionName.find()//it shows all documents in collection
```

please suggest solution for this problem.

Comment: facing the same issue.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462083/cannot-see-collections-in-robomongo-on-windows-10

Comment: I guess, you can raise an issue with robomongo github/issues...

Comment: k sir i will raise there.

Answer (score 6):

Robomongo 0.8.x is not compatible with MongoDB 3.x. Try MongoChef.

Answer (score 2):

You if you like to stick to Robomongo: the most current versions (0.9.x) now supports MongoDB 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Update your Robomongo with current version, It will solve your problem.

Comment: using robomongo 9.x  its working fine now. Thank you

Comment: @MendonAshwini You can mark it as answer, it would help other person having same type of issue.