# Cannot see collections in Robomongo on Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, robo3t

I searched thoroughly on internet but hardly found anything.

I have installed MongoDB (3.2.0) and Robomongo (0.8.5) on Windows 10. After installation I am able to start MongoDB as service successfully.
After this I restored the database with the help of DBRestore.exe which ran successfully.

Problem is I am not able to see collections in Robomongo. It is showing Collection(0).

EDIT: I have done this process couple of times on Windows 7 and completed it successfully. I am doing this first time on Windows 10.

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: 3.2.0 (mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.0-signed.msi)

Comment: I had the same problem. I moved over to using MongoChef after reading about others having the same issue. According to Karl-Johan Sjögren it only applies to WiredTiger, didn't know that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637624/mongodb-version-3-0-0-client-robomongo-mongovue

Answer (score 5):

Robomongo 0.8.x is not compatible with MongoDB 3.x. Try MongoChef.

**UPDATE 2015-12-17**: Just wanted to add a link to this Indiegogo campaign started by Dmitry Schetnikovich, the creator of Robomongo, which started a couple of days ago, and will be running up until the 8th of February 2016.

https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/save-robomongo

It also pretty much sums up Robomongo's current state.

**UPDATE 2016-01-27**: Robomongo 0.9.0 now supports the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-rc2-for-windows-mac-os-x-and-linux/

Comment: Oh ok. Will check MongoChef then. Hope its free :)

Comment: It is free for personal use.

Comment: @PrasadB just wanted to let you know that I updated the answer for Robomongo 0.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Robomongo doesn't support databases running with WiredTiger as storage engine. You need to setup your mongo instance to run on MMAPv1 instead if you want to use Robomongo. The issue can be [tracked here](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/520) though not much has been happening the past six months.

Comment: Is there any way I can stop MongoDB to use WiredTiger as Storage engine?

Comment: Sure, you can set it in your configuration file. Check the mongo documentation for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Robomongo 0.8 doesn't support mongodb version 3 because of having Weird tiger as default engine. So One have to download Robomongo new version 0.9 or above to use mongodb 3 versions.
IT is now available freely with wired tiger support from 27 jan 2016 having latest release version **1.0 RC1** .

One can download their corresponding platform verions from the link :- 
[Robomongo for mongodb 3+](https://robomongo.org/download)

Answer (score 0):

Using the right version of RoboMongo solved the similar issue I had. robomongo-0.9.0-rc8 (Updated on June 15th 2016)